# how to backup data in MySQL database automatically everyday to cloud

Tags: mysql, sql, database, backup

I have designed a web application and connected to MySQL database. Now i want to backup my data in the database automatically everyday as my data in database changes everday. When I have tried mysqldump through command line and export option through workbench i can only able to backup table structure but not data in it.

please someone tell me how to backup my data everyday to the cloud.any help is appreciated

Comment: What about setting up a master and slave? https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/configure-master-master-mysql-database-replication/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple php script + crontab to do that.

I am sharing a sample code for dumping data in csv format (*you can change this to any format you want by changing the given regular expression in the commands*):

```
exec('mysql -B -u '.$dbUser.' -p'.$dbPassword.' '.$dbName.' -h '.$dbHost.' -e "SELECT * FROM user;" | sed "s/\t/,/g" > '.$uploadPath.'user.csv');

exec('mysql -B -u '.$dbUser.' -p'.$dbPassword.' '.$dbName.' -h '.$dbHost.' -e "SELECT * FROM profile;" | sed "s/\t/,/g" > '.$uploadPath.'profile.csv');

---
---
---
```

Configure / generate the `$uploadPath` dynamically (*for example:* *`/var/log/yourApp/20160406/`*) in your script.

Run the script everyday with `crontab` (*assuming you are on linux server*):

```
1 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/yourscript.php
```

Everyday at `12.01am` your script will run the data will be backed up.

Comment: I don't know php crontab.Any other method?

Comment: `crontab` is not a `PHP` thing. It's a `job scheduler` - i mean in `linux OS` if you want to setup scheduled job - you can use `crontab`. It may differ in other OS. So basically you need to put the codes in a `PHP` file then setup `scheduled job` in your server to run the php file everyday at some time. `crontab` is only an example.

Comment: I am using windows os and  tomcat server.how can I do the same thing with task sheduler

Comment: Windows has a built-in `Task Scheduler` application. You can try and play around that. I haven't used tomcat before - so I can't tell you that. Thanks.